# Figure referencing throwing reference undefined on input line latex

Tags: floats

I'm trying to make a document and reference some figures that I have, however, some of them are displaying `Figure ??` when it's run. The way that I have declared the figures are

```
\begin{figure}[!h]
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{abc.png}
\caption{abc}
\label{fig:abc}
\end{figure}
```

and I've declared the figure by using `\ref{abc}` and I don't know why I'm getting the error.

Comment: Did you run latex twice?

Comment: @Au101 How do I do that? I mainly only use the Recompile button

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site! It would help if you could be a little bit more specific than 'the Recompile button', there are many editors - some designed specifically for LaTeX, some general purpose - and none of them are inherent to TeX/LaTeX, you can write it using Notepad, you can write it using emacs, vim, TeXworks, TeXShop, you can even write it straight on the Terminal. However, the point is, you have to compile twice. What editor are you using and what happens if you press that button and then press it again?

Comment: And you need to compile twice without deleting generated files in between (e.g. the `.aux` file).

Comment: You have `\label{fig:abc}` and `\ref{abc}`; the label and the reference should have the same string: `\ref{fig:abc}` will work.